# Is it considered old-fashioned these days to teach the normal forms in IT courses?

Tags: database-design

Do they teach database normalization at college these days?  Many of the questions from students here suggest they don’t.

Comment: six ears ago they did it once in germany :)

Answer (score 1):

Many of the answers suggest that some of the  experts learned data normalization on the fly, instead of formally.  In particular, many answers appear to disregard normal forms completely, and to treat all table decomposition as normalization regardless of whether or not the result conforms to some higher normal form.

It gets worse.  Many of the "normalization hawks" write as though they think that normalization is an all or nothing proposition.  Others write as if deviation from normal forms always results in an unsatisfactory design.  Still others write as if normalization were part of top down data design, rather than a manner of debugging a proposed or a legacy design.

On top of that, you have to realize that many of the askers and many of the experts are completely adapted to an environment where a database will be encapsulated within the scope of a single appplication, usually one to be sold to customers on a mass basis.  This is completely different from the environment for databases in the 1980s, when many of the classic texts on database design were originally written. At that time databases shared data between multiple applications and possibly multiple application development teams.

More than half of today's databases would be worthless for use with a report generator, let alone a second application.  And this is by intent, not by ignorance or accident.

In short, the question you raise is just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: Hm.  Is the notion of functional dependencies different in a context of shared databases, compared to a context of isolated databases ?  Redundancy and corresponding update anomalies are **exactly** the same in both environments, methinks.  Ditto for the notion of keys and ditto for the notion of join dependencies.  Ditto for the fact that a database updater **has to be aware of any possible update anomalies**.  Only difference there is in an "isolated" context, wrong and/or incomplete updates have less chance of proliferating all over the place.  But all the formal underpinnings are the same.

Comment: The principles are the same, as you say. However, the cost of getting it wrong is dramatically different. And the cost of learning the right way is balanced against much smaller returns on investment. So it's much more likely that a neophyte will be entrusted with the design of an embedded database than with the design of an enterprise critical database. I'm not trying to say the theory has changed. I'm saying the game has changed.